# Grab github repo and unzip in temp dir

Tags: r, unzip

I'd like to be able to grab a github repo and unzip its contents to a temporary directory.  I know there's functions that install_github in devtools but I'm not wanting to install, this is more generalizable to all github repos.

Here's what I've tried:

```
url <- "https://github.com/trinker/reports/zipball/master"
tmp <- tempfile( fileext = ".zip" )
download.file(url, tmp)
unzip(tmp, exdir = tempdir())
```

And this results in:

```
Warning message:
In unzip(tmp, exdir = tempdir()) : internal error in unz code
```

Again I'm not looking to install but have access to the internal files within a temp directory that I'll delete when exiting.

Comment: You can't download `https` urls with the default settings to `download.file`

Comment: That's gotten me before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `downloader` package which simplifies the download interface. Here is a function to achieve your goal.

```
#' Download and unzip Github repo to current directory
#'
#' @params repo name of github repository
#' @params user github user name
download_repo <- function(repo, user){
  require(downloader)
  url <- sprintf("https://github.com/%s/%s/archive/master.zip", user, repo)
  tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
  download(url, tmp)
  unzip(tmp)  
}

# download_repo('reports', 'trinker')
```